# Apply styles to a UserControl from within its own Xaml

Tags: wpf, user-controls, styles

Is there a way to apply styles (specifically style data triggers) to a `UserControl` within it's own XAML code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot access a Style in xaml within the UserControl's resources - you have a few options tho:

1. Set it in coding in the constructor through `Style = FindResource(<name>) as Style`
2. Set it in the Parent control `<local:MyUserControl Style="{StaticResource MyStyle}"`
3. Put the style in any Visual control's Resources-property 'up-the-chain' with an empty key and TargetType="{x:Type MyUserControl}"

Hope this helps.

Comment: I guess this makes sense.  The container determines how its controls look in WPF, correct?

Comment: Sort of - a container can apply styling to any child - but it can be overriden by containers/controls further down the chain.